SELinux inside of a Docker Container
Here How to enable SELinux inside of a CentOS Docker container? someone explains that SELinux cannot be used in a Docker Container, is this still valid?

Does this answer your question? How to enable SELinux inside of a CentOS Docker container?

I am asking if that is still valid (the answer is from almost 8 years ago)
